# Android - Won't allow me to implement a interface

Tags: android, interface, implements

Very strange error.  I'm trying to implement a simple interface in a non-activity class within my android application.  However, I get a run-time error.  If I remove the implementation, the code works fine.  I will let the code speak for itself,  feel free to chime in.  Thanks!

This throws a ClassNotFoundException when instantiating an instance of Globals

```
public class Globals implements IReceivable {

private volatile static Globals uniqueGlobal;
private static ClientSocket clientSocket;

private Globals()
{

}

public static Globals getInstance() {
    synchronized (Globals.class) {

        if (uniqueGlobal == null) {
            uniqueGlobal = new Globals();
            uniqueGlobal.InitializeClient();
        }
    }

    return uniqueGlobal;
}
@Override
public void MessageReceived(UUID clientId, String message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

When I remove it, everything works just fine

```
public class Globals  {

private volatile static Globals uniqueGlobal;
private static ClientSocket clientSocket;

private Globals()
{

}

public static Globals getInstance() {
    synchronized (Globals.class) {

        if (uniqueGlobal == null) {
            uniqueGlobal = new Globals();
            uniqueGlobal.InitializeClient();
        }
    }

    return uniqueGlobal;
}
```

}

**EDIT**

Here is the IReceivable interface

```
public interface IReceivable {

public void MessageReceived(UUID clientId, String message);
```

}

And the exact error:

> 12-02 10:14:15.859: E/AndroidRuntime(546):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.utilities.Globals

The line that is throwing the error looks like this:

```
 Globals global = Globals.getInstance();
```

Comment: can you please share the implementation of `IReceivable`

Comment: and also the error messages

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved the problem.  What I didn't tell you is that the interface is within a jar file that I have added to my project.

I added the jar file to my project and correctly included it into the build path, however, I did not add the jar file to the 'libs' folder.  Apparently, android at runtime will only include jar files that are within this folder.

Good learning experience for me.  Thanks!